# WinAPI: Open Named Mutex in Shell Extension for Preview and Current User Application

Tags: windows, shell-extensions, access-rights

I have a library that uses a named mutex to protect access to shared configuration data in the registry.

This library is now used both in a "normal" desktop application, and a Shell Preview extension handler. I observe the following behavior:

- If the mutex is created by the PrevHost.exe first (e.g. by previewing a file in explorer),
  the desktop application can open the mutex, and everything works.
- If the mutex is created by the desktop application first, the shell extension (running PrevHost.exe) can not open the mutex, failing with ACCESS DENIED.

I provide a `nullptr` security descriptor to `CreateMutex`.
How do I initialize a security descriptor that allows sharing the mutex between PrevHost.exe and a desktop application running under the current user?

Comment: If CreateMutex fails try OpenMutex.

Comment: @Dialecticus: this works! though I'm unsure why, as I understand the CreateMutex documentation, it would Open 8rather than create) the mutex in that situation anyway. --- Anyway, if you want to post as answer, I'd accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says that if `CreateMutex` succeeds then the mutex is created with all access privileges. But if the mutex is already created with reduced privileges then `CreateMutex` cannot expand on them, and so it fails. This is my interpretation, but I could be wrong.

The solution in any case is to follow up with `OpenMutex`.